# What cartoon featured insects who lived in a florist's shop and drank liquids to get superpowers?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Sorry I don't have much information guys, but this was a cartoon I watched way back as a kid. I'm assuming its 1980-1990 era, somewhere around there. I saw it in Sri Lanka, but I think it originated in America or the UK.

- It is basically about this insect or some very tiny creature and his family who live in a flower pot in a florists shop.
- The insect-like characters talk and interact, and the father is the one who mostly has these adventures sort of.
- The special thing is: inside their home (in the root of a plant I think) there is this cabinet full of jars, which contained all sorts of liquids which they would drink and they would get superpowers.
- I remember the shop door opening with a ring jingle.
- I think I remember the father wearing a tie and the mom always watering their home. It was a super simple cartoon, pretty 2D-ish.

I remember those magic jars all looked like a round amphoras, or similar to a Bocksbeutel wine bottle with a handle; and they were lined up on a shelf with like 2-3 rows and there were a good 20-50 of them at least.

Also I distinctively remember a dog in the petshop (it had a bloodhound look) and it kind of sniffs these guys and has random collaborations with them.

Also I found a picture very similar to the outside of the flowershop I remember.
It has that door jingle which I distinctively remember.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: It sounds like you've got a pretty vivid memory. Any chance of a sketch?

Comment: In which country did you watch this?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill  Hey Ernest, I watched this in my own country, Sri Lanka, but I'm sure its origins are from America or UK.

Comment: @Valorum  Haha,not the best sketcher I'm afraid :D But maybe the new picture of the outside of the flowershop might help. These creatures were really small, live in a plant root and the more I think about it, have Bee or like Fruit fly like features.

Comment: Hey guys, I found it. After ravenously looking around the oldest of forums in the internet and watching countless 1990's cartoon list videos I found what I was looking for. Its the 1997- The Herlufs by D'OCON. Much thanks for all who took interest to help answer. May I kindly know if I can close this question? Or mark it answered or is there need to do anything?

Comment: @ChrisChamika: Glad to know! Very hard to find, since you spoke about  insects, and those don't even look like insects, but like very tiny reptiles. Anyway, you can write an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: (oh, I forgot you added "or some very tiny creature")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the 1997 cartoon, The Herlufs by [D'OCON](https://www.doconfilms.com/). The Herlufs are tiny, orange-colored, vaguely reptilian creatures living between the roots of potted plants. The family of Herlufs resides in Pete's Flower Shop and has the same problems and joys as any other family, as well as having to battle spiders, dogs and runaway monster plants. They brew root essences giving them special powers, and use their tails as propellers to fly around.

Comment: Dear god, those things are terrifying.

Comment: @Harabeck You just haven't looked at their other offerings yet! Positively cute in comparison!